# What to talk about during end of term interview?

Tags: job-change, negotiation

I'm currently an apprentice about to reach the end of my agreed upon year, I have 11 days left to be exact.

I asked for an interview tomorrow about what is going to happen at the end of the agreed upon year, previously they plainly said they intended to hire me after the apprenticeship finished but since then there has been no talk of role, salary and formal employment.

I'm wondering what points I should bring up during the meeting to justify a reasonable salary, specific job title and contract if any.

I have 2 year previous experience with college education and of course my current 1 year experience in the field as well as knowledge of the system and existing relationships with the other employees.

Comment: Talk about: how does you boss think you're doing, what's good and what do you need to work on, and what happens next -- are they indeed planning to offer you longer term employment and if so at what pay rate and doing what. Then discuss/negotiate from there, remembering that if you push back too hard they can look for someone else. (If the offered pay is low, you might want to ask what they'd need to see from you to increase it, for example, rather than just complaining that you were hoping for more.)

Comment: Follow up letting us know how it went.  !RemindMe 10 days.

Comment: @user1717828 The meeting got pushed back to Thursday (Tomorrow). I'll be sure to let you know!

Comment: Got the job! WOOOOOOOOO!!!

Comment: You've actually left it a bit late to be asking for the interview.  I would have recommended asking for the interview at least a month before (if they *aren't* going to give you a place, you need advance warning so you can find other work). Congratulations on the new job btw!

Comment: Congratulations @S.Wessels. Consider self-answering your question now that you've gone through that interview with some apparent success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being clear and frank is always a great tactic.

You're in doubt, so tell them you want to know whether the company has future plans for you or not, and ask your boss what are these plans. You can also tell him about your expectations, and there's no big deal in asking about salary, or telling your expectations about it.

Just ensure to be polite and professional, and don't take anything to personal, regardless of the answers. And please, if it's not what you're expecting, don't worry to say goodbye and seek another open door. But it might be exactly what you're expecting.

And, happens a lot when you're beginning your career: sometimes we don't have a clear understanding of our expectations, so, knowing company's career plan, positions and benefits, etc, is a good plan. Talk to someone experienced in your field/position also helps.